1 min delay in Vue.js rendering
So i have an application which has django as backend and vue.js on the frontend. This app intereacts with a source with websocket connection and this source continuosuly sends values to the application. whenever these values exceed any nominal state, those exceeded values are added in the symtomslist and the main page displays the updated values instantly, as the watch function of the page is set to watch on symptomslist. So the problem i have is, when we logged in and started the simulation, the app has been rendering the new values instantly when the values were changed, but after somrtime, even if the values were changed, the page has been rendering them after 1 min(even though different people logged in at different times, the lag in rendering started to all of us at the same time). we timed it multiple times and it measured 1 min each time. but when we logout and log back in, the state is again being rendered instantly. can you tell what might be causing this issue
The console is logged every second. Maybe this is the issue?

The delay doesn't look like a performance issue. Need a [mre]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
